Are two Radon signed measures agreeing on compacts equal?
Let $X$ be a Hausdorff space and $\mu,\nu:\mathfrak{B}(X)\to \mathbb{R}$ two Radon signed measure (that is, $|\mu|$ and $|\nu|$ are Radon measures). If $\mu (K)=\nu (K)$ for all compacts $K\subseteq X$, can we conclude that $\mu =\nu $?

The proof is easy if $\mu ^-=\nu ^-=0$. However I don't know if we have that equality in the general case.

Yes. We have to show that $\mu(E)=\nu(E)$ for all $E\subseteq \mathfrak{B}(X)$, or $(\mu-\nu)(E)=0$ for all $E\subseteq \mathfrak{B}(X)$. Let $P$ and $N$ be a Hahn decomposition of $X$ for $\mu-\nu$. By inner regularity, if $\mu\neq\nu$, there would exist a compact set $K\subseteq P$ such that $(\mu-\nu)(K)>0$ or a compact set $K\subseteq N$ such that $(\nu-\mu)(K)>0$. By assumption, this is not the case.

Thank you very much!
